# How can I do alpha blending in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, alphablending

I have an html file with a function that used in it but defined in another file. This is the main file that will use this function (composite()):

```
function recomputeImage()
{
    var layers = document.getElementById('layers');
    if ( layers.children.length == 0 ) return;
    if ( layers.lastChild.image ) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width  = layers.lastChild.image.width;
        canvas.height = layers.lastChild.image.height;
        var image = new ImageData( layers.lastChild.image.data.slice(), 
                                   layers.lastChild.image.width, 
                                   layers.lastChild.image.height );
        if ( layers.lastChild.imageOpac < 1 ) {
            for ( var i=3; i<image.data.length; i+=4 ) {
                image.data[i] *= layers.lastChild.imageOpac;
            }
        }
        for ( var i=layers.children.length-2; i>=0; --i ) {
            var c = layers.children[i];
            if ( c.image ) {
                composite( image, c.image, c.imageOpac, c.imagePos );
            }
        }
        context.putImageData( image, 0, 0 );
    }
}
```

My goal is to define this function in a way that do alpha blending (pixle color = fgColor * fgOpacity + (1 - fgOpacity) * bgColor). So I defined this function as below with assuming that each data attribute of image object contains a series of "rgba" data so I excluded the "Alpha" by the "continue" statement line as below:

```
function composite( bgImg, fgImg, fgOpac, fgPos )
{
    var j = 0;
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < fgImg.data.length; ++i, ++j)
    {
        if(i%4 == 3)
            continue;
        if(i % fgImg.width == 0)
        {
            if(count > 0)
                j = bgImg.width * count;

            ++count;
        }

        bgImg.data[j] = 
            fgImg.data[i] * fgOpac + (1 - fgOpac) * bgImg.data[j];
    }
}
```

I think the code should working but here it is the result:
[image]
The foreground image is broken into seprate pieces. I also have problem in using the fgPos argument; it should be used in this code in a way that user can move the foreground image.

I want to drag images in my main file and each image capable of moving while alpha blending happens in each pixle between the images. Obviously I tried the above code (and some other code blocks), but I didn't get any result.
The complete file [link](https://mega.nz/file/0Q0H0BQJ#0KyejsdrWPusX7hWY4L2ZiirDZ3PVtxzMHufL3OkS8E) and again the composite function (the above code) is defined in another file.

Comment: Is moving an image so that it is only partially in frame of the background area) going to be supported? If so, `composite` looks like it would need more logic to check subscripts in two dimensions, not one, to check if foreground pixels are within the background area.

Comment: @traktor Yeah you're right, but before the moving thing the code should display the image in the correct form. What can I do about this messy form?

Comment: I'd love to look into it further but don't have time to write test code. Can you add enough HTML and glue code to the post for me (and others) to test it? Any image urls will do, but if you choose random images on imgr.com I won't have to change them. Thx.

Comment: @traktor Thanks for your time. The link to the complete file is appended to the end of the question. You can use any image. I test this code with other images and I got the same result.

Comment: For future reference, guidelines for asking questions on the help site are to include cut down test cases in the question itself, not the entire project file somewhere offsite. For example, loading the project script file, the keyboard handler to do that and providing drag and drop facilities which are not needed to demonstrate the issue are clutter that should not be included in a test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `composite` function is at fault. Rewriting from scratch using the same arguments proves it:

```js
function composite( bgImg, fgImg, fgOpac, fgPos ) {
    let bgIndex = fgPos.x + fgPos.y * 4*bgImg.width;
    let fgIndex = 0;
    for( var y=0; y < fgImg.height; ++y, bgIndex += 4*bgImg.width) {
        for( var x = 0; x < fgImg.width; ++x, fgIndex += 4) {
            for( var color = 0; color<3; ++color) {
                bgImg.data[bgIndex + 4*x + color] = 
                  fgImg.data[fgIndex + color] * fgOpac + (1 - fgOpac) * bgImg.data[bgIndex + 4*x + color]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The rewrite was iterative right up until it worked when included in the HTML linked offsite. No claim of "good", "best" or "optimized" is made - it is missing a lot of code to detect invalid arguments or  positioning of the foreground image either partially or completely outside the background Image. Feel free to rewrite `composite` from its specification or modify the above so it makes perfect sense to you as a learning exercise. I suggest not trying to optimize it until after you have it working.

Answer (score 1):

The way you compute `j` is broken. Like `if(i % fgImg.width == 0)`, i changes 4 times per pixel ... and as traktor already mentioned, this entire logic is a bit sparse for what you're trying to do.

Didn't test the code, but it should be something like this:

```
const clamp = (value, min, max) => value > min ? value < max ? value : max : min;

function composite(bgImg, fgImg, fgOpac, { x: offsetX, y: offsetY }) {

  // find the intersecting rectangle of the two (offset) images
  const top = clamp(offsetY, 0, bgImg.height);
  const bottom = clamp(offsetY + fgImg.height, 0, bgImg.height);
  const left = clamp(offsetX, 0, bgImg.width);
  const right = clamp(offsetX + fgImg.width, 0, bgImg.width);

  const t = fgOpac, u = 1 - t;

  // process each row
  for (let y = top; y < bottom; ++y) {
    // compute the indices for both images
    let i = 4 * (y * bgImg.width + left);
    let j = 4 * ((y - offsetY) * fgImg.width + (left - offsetX));

    // process row, pixel by pixel
    for (let x = left; x < right; ++x, i += 4, j += 4) {
      // either background is opaque and you fade in the fgImg on top of it, 
      // then you need to include the pixels transparency
      // const t = fgOpac * fgImg.data[fg+3], u = 1 - t;

      bgImg.data[i + 0] = u * bgImg.data[i + 0] + t * fgImg.data[j + 0];
      bgImg.data[i + 1] = u * bgImg.data[i + 1] + t * fgImg.data[j + 1];
      bgImg.data[i + 2] = u * bgImg.data[i + 2] + t * fgImg.data[j + 2];
      // or you cross fade the alpha channel as well 
      // and let the browser mix this with what's behind the canvas.
      bgImg.data[i + 3] = u * bgImg.data[i + 3] + t * fgImg.data[j + 3];
    }
  }
}
```